# running a query that displays specific locations that match dependent criteria (ruby)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `locations` and I have `ticket_locations`.  The `locations` have many `ticket_locations`.  What I need to do is pull in only specific `locations` that own a specific type of `ticket_locations` that match a certain kind of ID.

I've been able to pull the `locations`, and I've been able to pull in the `ticket_locations`.

My ID's that I need to be set are

```
identify = [2, 3]
```

My search for the parent locations is below. This gives me three locations. (yes they are owned by customers)

```
locations_query = Location.joins(:customers).where('customers.id in (?)', @customers.map(&:id))
```

My search for the `ticket_locations` is below. This gives me 5 `ticket_locations`. 2 belong to the first location. 2 belong to the second location, and only 1 belongs to the third.

```
ticket_locations = LocationTicket.where(ticket_id: identify)
```

What I need (and am struggling with) is to run a search for the parent Locations that only pull in the locations that have `ticket_locations` that match both IDs in the `identify` array.

I've tried something along the lines of

```
master_ticket_locations = locations_query.where(ticket_id: zip_ticket_locations)
```

But since `ticket_id` is a class name in the `ticket_locations` and not the `locations_query` i've been having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `join` operator. Just like you did in locations_query for the `customers` table, you need to join `ticket_locations`. Assuming thats the name of the relationship:

```
master_ticket_locations = locations_query.joins(:ticket_locations).where(ticket_locations: {ticket_id: identify})
```

See the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) for more info